# Storing HDF5 subsets as datasets (in python)

Tags: python, hdf5

I have only limited knowledge of HDF5 but I would like to understand something about HDF selections.

To give some context I'm interested in using HDF5 for applications in machine learning. Suppose you have a data matrix with `n` rows and `p` columns. In a typical `k`-folds cross-validation setting, you will split the matrix into `k` samples (each one of size `(n/k, p)`) and repetitively use `k-1` for training and 1 for testing. Of course, storing all the training and testing sets will use a lot of space. This is where HDF5 selections could help.

If I understand correctly, a selection can refer to any subset of a dataset. Moreover a selection can be stored into a dataset. Therefore, starting from a `(n, p)` dataset in HDF5, I could create `k` groups (one for each fold), containing a training dataset (a subset of the rows in the original dataset) and a testing dataset (the remainder). As it's only references, it won't use too much space.

I have found some documentation about selections but it's not very clear. The code examples are in C which is a bit harsh to modify and I mainly use Python. I haven't found anything related to this in `PyTables`. I have found [some examples in `h5py`](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/refs.html) but I couldn't figure how to put data in the subset.

Can anybody confirm that this is an interesting approach and provide some python code for storing a subset of rows from a dataset as another dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to almost do that thanks the h5py community. See the thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h5py/P-fJCLGxcuc).

Comment: Hi Mathieu, thank you for this post -- it was very helpful to me. Do you know if it is possible to create a reference to a file in read-only mode? When I try this I get an error `ValueError: Unable to create reference (no write intent on file)`. I wondered if it might be possible to write a reference to a file which points to a separate read-only dataset. Can you offer any thought on this?

Comment: Sorry I haven't worked on that since 2015... Maybe try the h5py forums, they have been very kind and helpful.

Comment: Can you update the answer to show concretely how you did the train val test splits?